# Subset / group by pandas Data Frame to calculate mean and apply to missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subset pandas dataframe by a group / category, calculate a statistic and apply it to the original dataframe for missing values in the group.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'City': ['SF','NYC','SF','NYC','SF','CHI','LA','LA','CHI'], 
                    'Val': [2,4,0,0,7,4,3,5,6] 
                   })

for name, group in df.groupby(['City']):

    dff = df[df['City'] == name]

    # Calculate mean
    df1 = dff[dff['Val'] != 0]
    mean_val = int(df1['Val'].mean())
```

Now, I need to apply `mean_val` to all `0s` in the subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) out the 0 values then [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) to calculate the mean and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to put the means back, lastly convert the column to `int` using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
s = df['Val'].mask(df['Val'].eq(0))
df['Val'] = s.fillna(s.groupby(df['City']).transform('mean')).astype(int)
```

Or we can boolean index where Val is 0, [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) out the 0 values and assign the results of [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) back using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['Val'].eq(0)
df.loc[m, 'Val'] = (
    df['Val'].mask(m)
        .groupby(df['City']).transform('mean')
        .astype(int)
)
```

Both produce:
`df`:

```
  City  Val
0   SF    2
1  NYC    4
2   SF    4
3  NYC    4
4   SF    7
5  CHI    4
6   LA    3
7   LA    5
8  CHI    6
```

---

We *could* filter `dff` to get the index locations relative to `df` and assign back to modify the original approach:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['City']):

    dff = df[df['City'] == name]

    # Calculate mean
    df1 = dff[dff['Val'] != 0]
    mean_val = int(df1['Val'].mean())
    # Assign mean back to `df` at index locations where Val is 0 in group
    df.loc[dff[(dff['Val'] == 0)].index, 'Val'] = mean_val
```

Although looping is *highly* discouraged in pandas due to increased runtime.

However, if we are going to use the iterable from `groupby` we should use the values returned instead of filtering from `df`:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(['City']):
    # Create Boolean Index
    m = group['Val'] != 0
    # Calculate mean from grouped dataframe `group`
    mean_val = int(group.loc[m, 'Val'].mean())
    # Assign mean back to `df` at index locations where Val is 0 in group
    df.loc[group[~m].index, 'Val'] = mean_val
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['SF', 'NYC', 'SF', 'NYC', 'SF', 'CHI', 'LA', 'LA', 'CHI'],
    'Val': [2, 4, 0, 0, 7, 4, 3, 5, 6],
})
```

Comment: I added a second part to the question, where I need to create a new column excl. `0s` in `df['Val']` and fill the value for the new col. @HenryEcker if you have any thoughts

Comment: 2 things. (1) it's generally bad form to change your question in such a way that adds additional requirements which invalidates my answer if I don't update it. (2) what do you mean "and apply the `mean` of the group to `df1['new col']` where `df['Val'] = 0`."

Comment: If you provided sample output that would be helpful in my understanding what you meant.